# Volume of the solid obtained by rotating half-disk around an axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> Consider the portion of the Cartesian plan delimited, in the first quadrant, from $x=0$, from $y=0$ and from the circumference of radius $= 1$ with center in the point $(0; 1)$, and determine the volume of the solid that generates a full rotation around $x=0$.

[image]

#### Progress

This is my tentative of solving the problem but i don't understand why the book says that the result is $\pi/  3$.

$x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ is the equation of the circumference centered on $(0; 1)$

$x^2 + y^2 + 1 - 2y = 1$

$x^2 + y^2 -2y = 0$

$x = \sqrt{2y - y^2}$

I don't understand what surface I have to rotate.

Could you help me, please?

I don't understand if the surface to rotate is the pseudotriangle 0AB (in red), or the semicircle coloured in green.

Of course the center of the circle is in $(0; 1)$, the length of 0A is 1, and the length of AB is 1.

Thinking about this problem, I realize that - in my opinion - the green surface measures:

PiGreco * 1^2 /2 = PiGreco / 2

A full rotation around x=0 is a sphere.  The volume of a sphere is: 4 PiGreco * R^3 / 3

We have R = 1 so the volums SEEMS to be: 4 PiGreco / 3.

BUT the book says that the result is PiGreco / 3

Who is right? Who is wrong?  Did I misunderstood the surface to rotate around x=0?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have edited my questions adding my tentative.

Comment: I have added the picture, I think it is so!

Comment: I voted to reopen and also formatted the formulas. Meanwhile, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Comment: Thank you for considering my question! ;-)

Comment: If the answer is $\pi/3$, it's for the red thing. You can find it geometrically: think of rotating the line segment $x=1$ (from $(1;0)$ to $(1;1)$) around $x=0$. This creates a cylinder, of volume $2\pi$. Subtract the volume of the sphere (green), and you'll get the red part together with its mirror image near the top of cylinder. So, divide by two, and you'll get $\pi/3$.

Comment: My God, if you write it as YOUR answer, I can accept it and let you gain points! ;-)  I cannot vote up to your comments, I am too stackexchange young! ;-)

Comment: In all fairness, the wording of the problem really sucks. Don't feel bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found, the   volume of the green part is $4\pi/3$, so it can't be the one they want.

The volume of the red part  can be found  geometrically, without integration.   Think of rotating the vertical line segment  with endpoints $(1;0)$ and $(1;1)$  around the axis $x=0$. This creates a cylinder  of height $2$ and radius $1$, hence of volume $2\pi$.  Subtract the volume of the sphere which you know, and you'll get the red part together with its mirror image near the top of cylinder. Divide by two to get the volume of the red part.

---

Aside: Archimedes found that the volume of a  ball inscribed into a cylinder is $2/3$ of the volume of the cylinder.  He was so proud of this   result that  he asked for a sketch of a sphere inscribed in a cylinder to be   on his grave. [On the Sphere and Cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sphere_and_Cylinder)